# how to suppress error from .vim plugin vimIM

Tags: vim

there will be lots of error while open with vim, it seems g: function cannot be recognized which come from vimIM plugin, a Chinese input methord.

```
Error detected while processing ~/.vim/plugin/vimim.vim:
line  473:
E128: Function name must start with a capital or "s:": g:vimim_slash()
line  474:
E121: Undefined variable: s:starts
E15: Invalid expression: col(".") - 1 - s:starts.column
line  475:
E121: Undefined variable: s:starts
E116: Invalid arguments for function strpart(getline("."), s:starts.column, range)
E15: Invalid expression: strpart(getline("."), s:starts.column, range)
line  476:
E121: Undefined variable: chinese
```

there are 3 vim located in my macbook

```
/usr/bin/vim
/Cellar/vim/7.4.430/bin/vim
/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim-snapshot-72/mvim
```

and vim in use link to Cellar one

```
$ which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/vim
/usr/local/bin/vim -> ../Cellar/vim/7.4.430/bin/vim
```

however if open with mvim, it'll be quite

```
$ which mvim
/usr/local/bin/mvim
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/mvim
/usr/local/bin/mvim -> /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim-snapshot-72/mvim
```

Comment: Report problems on the issue tracker (if there is one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your homebrew-cask-installed Vim has patches 1-430 so it exhibits that behavior which appeared sometime around patch 260.

On the other hand, your homebrew-installed MacVim has only patches 1-52 so it doesn't exhibit that behavior.

Like FDinoff commented, this issue should be submitted to the plugin's author. Even if it's linked to a Vim "bug", the author should look into it because there's no reason whatsoever to "scope" functions in Vimscript.

Also, why the hell do you have so many Vims on your machine? I can understand two (the default one and a better one), but… three?

Comment: thanks, so you mean the warning message can only suppress/correct in vimIM plugin even if it's no harm.  
the Cellar and homebrew-cask seems all from "brew install", I don't know why.